# Selecting and Slicing Columns Which are a PeriodIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame where the columns are a PeriodIndex by Month as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,4), index = np.arange(3), columns = pd.period_range('2015-01', freq = 'M', periods = 4))


     2015-01     2015-02    2015-03      2015-04
0   -1.459943   -1.572013   2.977714    -0.067696
1   -1.545259   -0.570757   0.133756    -1.231192
2    0.498197   -0.555625   0.174545     0.371475
```

I can select a subset of columns as follows:

```
testdf[[pd.Period('2015-01'),pd.Period('2015-03')]]

     2015-01    2015-03
0   -1.459943   2.977714
1   -1.545259   0.133756
2    0.498197   0.174545
```

However when it comes to slicing to get for example all months from '2015-01' to '2015-03' I am stumped as to the syntax required. I have tried all kinds of iterations without luck.

For example:

```
df[pd.Period('2015-01'):pd.Period('2015-03')]
df['2015-01':'2015-03']
```

All of which do not work.

How can I slice this PeriodIndex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.ix` to pass a slice for the column selection arg:

```
In [9]:
df.ix[:,pd.Period('2015-01'):pd.Period('2015-03')]

Out[9]:
    2015-01   2015-02   2015-03
0  0.046028 -0.298445  0.908185
1 -0.955049 -1.420290  1.632564
2  0.848906  0.089553  0.551265
```

Comment: For any slicing I'll be sure to remember to use .ix in future. Thank you :)